# excel vba button to loop range and increase value

Tags: excel, vba

Need help, anyone can teach me how to make the button go back to original value after it looped or reached the last one? eg. i set loop value from 1 to 10, after 10 it should go back to 1.

```
Sub LOOP_BUTTON()
    Sheet17.[L2] = Sheet17.[L2].Value + 1
End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT : 1***

```
Sub Demo()
    If Sheet17.[L2].Value = 10 Then
        Sheet17.[L2].Value = 1
    Else
        Sheet17.[L2] = Sheet1.[L2] + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

***EDIT : 2*** If you want result as `1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1`

```
Public IsDecrease As Boolean

Sub Demo()
    If IsDecrease Then
        If Sheet17.[L2].Value = 1 Then
            IsDecrease = False
            Sheet17.[L2].Value = 2
        Else
            Sheet17.[L2] = Sheet17.[L2] - 1
        End If
    Else
        If Sheet17.[L2].Value = 6 Then
            IsDecrease = True
            Sheet17.[L2].Value = 5
        Else
            Sheet17.[L2] = Sheet17.[L2] + 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: hi thanks, where do i fit this code inside your code?  Sheet17.[L2] = Sheet17.[L2].Value - 1

Comment: Hi, sorry one more question, how to make it reverse? eg. from value 6, go back to 5,4,3,2,.....

Comment: @robin - Do you mean `1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1`?

Comment: Yes correct, i tried to minus 1 "Sheet17.[L2] = Sheet1.[L2] - 1" but not working

Comment: @robin - Suppose you have value `4` in `Sheet17.[L2]`, then how you'll know that the next value has to be `4+1` or `4-1`?

Comment: I thought when 1 set the value from 1 to 6, maxium is 6, so it stop there, next number either is 5 or 1, can it be done?

Comment: @robin - When `Sheet17.[L2]` is `6`, it can be changed to `5` but then what? If you go by above logic `5` will be changed to `6` again and not `4`. Or you want to change `6`  to `1`?

Comment: Hi, the sequence is from 1 to 6, so at 6, if click it will go to 1, if click another button it go back to 5, so I guess I need two buttons to do this right?

Comment: @robin - If you want result as `1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1`,see `Edit 2` in answer.

Comment: Hi look good. Let me try later. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Hi, your code edit 2 work perfectly! once again thank you and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mod`:

```
Sub LOOP_BUTTON()
    Sheet17.[L2] = (Sheet17.[L2].Value Mod 10) + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but it's not working, the number continue to increase not stop at 10 and go back to 1.

Comment: @robin Is this `Sub` the **only** piece of code updating cell L2 on the sheet which has the `CodeName` of `Sheet17`?

Comment: hi yes, L2 is the single cell, when i click the button the L2 value will increase, thank you for your help

Comment: In that case, when the value is 10 and you click it again the `(10 Mod 10)` will evaluate to `0` and `0 + 1` will result in `1` being placed into the cell.

Comment: hi, yes, re-test your code and also working, thank you very much!